# Converting a hexadecimal number represented in ASCII characters to a decimal integer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, hex, ascii

my problem is as follows.

I'm reading a piece of ascii data from a sensor, let's say it's "400". It's stored in an array of characters. In hex (ascii) that would be { 0x34, 0x30, 0x30 }.

What I'm trying to get from that set of characters is an integer in decimal representative of hex 0x400, which would be 1024. All the other numeric values in this array of ascii characters are represented in decimal, so I've been using this:

```
int num_from_ascii(char reading[], int start, int length){
    printf("++++++++num_from_ascii+++++++++\n");
    char radar_block[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        radar_block[i] = reading[start + i];
        printf("%02x ", reading[start + i]);
    }
  printf("\n");
  return atoi(radar_block);
}
```

This obviously just gives me back 400, but I need a decimal integer from a hex value. Any advice?

Comment: My question would be whether you're supposed to read individual values literally or not.

Comment: The sample I'm pulling from is certainly supposed to be 1024, so I'm confident in the values supplied and how they're read if that helps.

Comment: `strtoul` will handle most of the work for you

Comment: You can't really do that without converting to number first. Read `400` as string, convert that to `int` and print that `int` as decimal.

Comment: That part is already done via that function in the post. That would return to me an integer representing 400, but the integer isn't 400 it's supposed to be 0x400 or 1024 (the integer I want)

Comment: Which language are you using, C or C++? They're different. The code shown is not legal C++ (because of the Variable Length Array).

Comment: @user3121023: NUL termination would also be necessary for `atoi`... it's definitely a bug in the code in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the backup everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eugene has suggested, all you need to do is replace `atoi(radar_block)` by `strtol(radar_block, NULL, 16)`.  That takes a "base" argument, which can be `10` for decimal, `16` for hex (which is what you want), etc or `0` to auto-detect using the C++ rules (leading "0x" for hex, leading "0" for octal).

You should never use `atoi` anyway because it does not handle invalid inputs safely.  `strtol` does everything that `atoi` does, has well defined errno for all edge cases, and also allows you to distinguish `"0"` from non-numeric input.

As user3121023 mentioned, don't forget to NUL-terminate the string you pass to `strtol` (this is a serious bug in your code calling `atoi` as well).

Comment: Thank you for the help